# Sonar execution via jenkins, sonar processing continue even after ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL message

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am facing an issue while running sonar through Jenkins, after configuration when I making build by build now trigger my build runs and creating EAR successfully then sonar deployment starts which also run successfully and showing ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL in the end of Jenkins build processing but even after successful analysis of sonar build continue to process and it never ends even after a long time wait. Very last line of build processing is
"12:55:14.159 INFO  - <- Delete aborted builds"
pls see attached screenshot to refer.[image]

can anybody help me out over this issue?
what is the reason behind this continuous processing of sonar analysis?
it never complete. what should I do at my end to complete build process so that my build become successful in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Jenkins. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: but I can't restart Jenkins again and again as I am using it in a centralized way on centralized server in my organization..

Answer (score 0):

The ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL message just means that all sensors and decorators have completed. There are still some post-analysis tasks which must take place (specifically, any class extending [PostJob](http://docs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/org/sonar/api/batch/PostJob.html)). I've found that the final log output message is not always an accurate indicator of what's wrong. There are some plugins which churn forever but don't produce any output. But I wouldn't be surprised if your analyses really *are* stuck at "Delete aborted builds." Sometimes the Database Cleaner can take a *long* time, but if it's more than 10 minutes, it's stuck. It's very likely a problem with database interaction.

The way to continue is to enable all possible SQL tracing. Enable all the options -- sonar.showProfiling=true, sonar.showSql=true, sonar.showSqlResults=true, and sonar.verbose=true. See the [Sonar Analysis Parameters](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) for more information.

If *that* doesn't tell you what's wrong, you might have some luck getting more information out of sonar.log by editing wrapper.conf to show DEBUG log output.